# How to send push notifications to the use on Flutter Android App?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, flutter, dart

I developed an Android application using the **flutter**. My **database is MongoDB**. I **connected the android App with the MongoDb using Node.js API**. now I want to **send push notifications to the user** when the **new data record is added to the database**. How Can I Do That? I'm new to Flutter.

Comment: Have you tried finding something online? what did you come up with?

Comment: This is firebase My database is MongoDB. Can I use this method as well as with MongoDB?